# Ember.js Best Practices - Can/Should I override sendAction?

Tags: ember.js

In my Ember App, I have a large number of modal dialog components that I render in my Application route like so:

```
{{component modalComponent options=modalOptions}}
```

All dialog components extend from a single base class, where, for convenience, I have overridden `sendAction`.  The point of the override is to *always* trigger some action on the `target`, as opposed to `sendAction`'s default behavior of "if the property is undefined, do nothing".  Here is what that looks like:

```
sendAction: function (actionName) {
  if (Em.isEmpty(this.get(actionName))) {
    this.set(actionName, actionName);
  }
  this._super(...arguments);
},
```

This seems to work as I would expect: always triggering an action on the target that will then bubble up the stack.  What I'm wondering is...

**Are there any implications/side-effects of overriding `sendAction` that I am not aware of?**

Answer (score 0):

Currently, one of the more accepted ways to handle actions in components is through closure actions:

In template:

`{{do-button id="save" clickHandler=(action "storeEvent") contextMenuHandler=(action "logEvent") buttonText="Store It"}}`

In component:

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Component.extend({
  actions: {
    clickHandler(event) {
      this.get('clickHandler')(event);
    },

    contextMenuHandler(event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      this.get('contextMenuHandler')(event);
    }
  }
});
```

And finally, an excerpt from the controller:

```
  actions: {
    doStuff(event) {
      alert(event);
    },
    logEvent(event) {
      console.log(event);
    },
```

So basically, you are taking the action passed into the component and calling it, passing in whatever arguments you want to from the component.  Closure actions are pretty sweet, and they make working with actions a lot easier.  Hope this gets your wheels turning :)